# PhpStorm 2016.2 Change the Debug Panel Font Size

Tags: fonts, phpstorm

The editor and the console font size can be changed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>mouse wheel</kbd> ([ref](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/zooming-in-the-editor.html)), but how do you change the **debug panel** font size? I've been all through `Colors & Fonts` and haven't been able to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to change font size **only** for *Debug, Run* etc. tabs. But you can change font for whole IDE in `File | Settings | Appearance & Behaviour | Appearance` and here check `Override default fonts` option and change font size.

P.S. Try to use [Grep Console](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125) plugin to make logs more readable.

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to change the console font. It's the debug panel, with all the variables and array contents at a breakpoint, that I'm trying to increase the font size of.

Comment: Opps. Sorry @Drakes. Please check my updates.

Comment: Good job. Just what was needed. Thanks for the help.